# can't run android app on galaxy stellar

Tags: android, eclipse

I cannot get my android app to run on a Galaxy Stellar phone 4.12 OS from Eclipse on Windows 7.  When I plug in the phone, it shows that it is installing a driver and it also shows the phone data in a directory window.  I set my run configuration to look for all available devices but doesn't recognize the device saying "No active compatible AVD's or devices found."  I know others have this problem and I have researched it but I still can't get my app to run on anything other than an emulator.   I have the Google USB driver installed according to my SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Samsung's driver instead?  http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I200ZKAVZW

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I downloaded the samsung driver and now I am in business.  Thank God for Stack Oveflow.